# How does having no Con score affect an Undead Kineticist's blasts?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics, undead

I have been perusing the Occult Adventures content and like the concept of a [Kineticist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist). I was about to add a few as enemies in my undead-focused campaign, when I remembered Undead have no Constitution score. I know this means my Kineticist cannot accept burn, but what does that mean for damage on kinetic blasts? Most undead templates state that Charisma is used for HP, so would that work for blast damage? Or do they simply do not get extra blast damage due to stats?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [Undead Type](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Undead) description:

> Undead **use their Charisma score** in place of their Constitution score when calculating hit points, Fortitude saves, and **any special ability that relies on Constitution** (such as when calculating a breath weapon's DC).

That includes Kineticist's blasts.